# How to close json popUp which is open by partial view after save in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in MVC.  I am using MVC 5.how to close a popup after create / save.
Here is my view code:-

```
 <div id='OpenDilog'></div>` function CreateEmployee() {
    var div = $("#OpenDilog");
    div.load("/Category/Create", function () {
        div.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            title: "Add New Details",
            resizable: false
        });

    });

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using jQuery.Ui to create your dialog, you can add a "Close" button like this:

```
div.dialog({
    buttons: [
        {   text: 'Close',
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    ]      
});
```

Same goes for the "Create" button. Just add `$(this).dialog('close');` at the end of the Create button click handler.

Comment: Dear Georg thanks for reply. my requirement is diffrent here. if I add this is working , but I want to use when I add a record my pop up should automaically closed. I have used below link for my stuff you can see the details. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/mvc-curd-operation-using-jquery-json-and-linq-to-sql-class/

Comment: In the example you have shown, there are `SaveEmployee()` methods that post the Create form through Ajax. In the line `$.post("/EmployeeInfo/Create", Employee,  
        function (data) { /* put your success handler code here */ }, 'json');` you can define a callback function that runs after the post was successful. You have to get a reference to your popup dialog in there somehow, for example use a known ID for the dialog container element.

Comment: Thanks Georg if possible send me a example or any link.